# ClassNotFoundException when I use design support library

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, androiddesignsupport

When I use design support library, my app crashed.
Logcat shows as follow:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.android.design.support.FloatingActionButton
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.design.support.FloatingActionButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.lmy86263.designsupportlibrarydemo-1/base.apk"],

I add `com.android.support:design:22.2.0` to the gradle and sync, but it doesn't work.

Any solutions?

Comment: Did you download the support library via sdk manager?

Comment: yes, Android Support library 22.2

Comment: In your xml the `FloatingActionButton` should be as this----> `<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`, I think you have it incorrectly added in your layout file. Can you post the layout file too.

Answer (score 4):

In your xml the FloatingActionButton should be as this----> `<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`, 
you have it incorrectly added in your layout file hence you are getting the error.

Eg:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```